# Date conversion error in dynamic table value filter

Tags: vba, excel, date, dynamic-tables

Working with excel-Access VBA environment. The vba code in the excel page assigns the value of a date cell to the date filter. Since I always work dd/mm/yyyy format with panama locale, the code works fine for dates after the 12th (meaning there's no ambiguity to designate the month), but for days les than 13, it converts the day to its numeric value and I get an error message saying 42502 (for may 12,2016 for example) is not a valid value for the filter. When the day passes the 12th, it works fine. How can i trap this error and solve it ?

Code :

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

    ' Range R1 contains the value we desire to filter the date of dynamic table

    ' Range B1 contains the date filter of the dynamic table    

    Range("B1").Select

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("fecha").ClearAllFilters

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = Range("R1").Value
    ff = Range("R1").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = Right("00" & Day(ff), 2) & "/" & Right("00" & Month(ff), 2) & "/" & Year(ff)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This is one of the many ways Ive tried to solve this, but only works for days after the 12th of the month

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - can you please post your code so that we can understand what it's actually doing?

Comment: ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
    ' Range R1 contains the value we desire to filter the date of dynamic table
    ' Range B1 contains the date filter of the dynamic table 
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("fecha").ClearAllFilters
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = Range("R1").Value
    ff = Range("R1").Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1") = Right("00" & Day(ff), 2) & "/" & Right("00" & Month(ff), 2) & "/" & Year(ff)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Comment: Please edit your original post with the code, not in the comments as it's unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you posted some code, but I believe the problem is you need to specify in code what format you are using instead of letting VBA guess it for you.  Since Microsoft is a US company and we use the MM/DD/YYYY format, it could be defaulting to the US format, but then when it reaches the 13th, it defaults to the non-US format by the context of the date.

Comment: This really is a comment as it only says why, not how to overcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim lastRow, i As Long
Dim datStg As String

lastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    dateStg = Cells(i, "R").Text
    If datStg <> "" Then
        Cells(i, "B").Value = DateSerial(Mid(dateStg, 8, 4), Mid(dateStg, 5, 2), Mid(dateStg, 2, 2))
        Cells(i, "B").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End If
Next i
```